# javascript check if array contains more than one element with exact same property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
[
  {
   id: 1,
   sku: 'aaaa'
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   sku: 'bbbb'
  },
  {
   id: 3,
   sku: 'cccc'
  },
  {
   id: 4,
   sku: 'aaaa'
  }
]
```

How can I check that there are more than one element with the same `sku` property existing in the array?

For example: I have to elements with the same prop `sku` ('aaaa') - and in this case I need to do something in other case - nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: please add the wanted result and your try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use set to get an array holding unique skus and compare the length

```
var skus = items.map(v=>v.sku);
var uniqueSkus = new Set(skus);
console.log(skus.length === uniqueSkus.size)
```

Comment: It is [`Set.prototype.size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size), not `.length`

Comment: consider turning your code block into live snippet to demonstrate your concept in action

Answer (score 0):

You can use example code like this:

```js
var a = [
  {
   id: 1,
   sku: 'aaaa'
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   sku: 'bbbb'
  },
  {
   id: 3,
   sku: 'cccc'
  },
  {
   id: 4,
   sku: 'aaaa'
  }
];

var b = {};
a.forEach(el => {
  if (b[el.sku]) {
    b[el.sku].count++;
  } else {
    b[el.sku] = { id: el.id, count: 1 };
  }
});

console.log(b);
```

Comment: In order to answer OP's question you'll need to iterate once again through `Object.values(b)` to find out whether there exists `count > 1`, so, it's, basically, half of the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can check like below array function 'some' will help you

```
 var arr = [
  {
   id: 1,
   sku: 'aaaa'
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   sku: 'bbbb'
  },
  {
   id: 3,
   sku: 'cccc'
  },
  {
   id: 4,
   sku: 'aaaa'
  }
]

const val = 'aaaa'

const isAvailable = arr.some(function(arrVal) {
        return val === arrVal.sku;
});

//here isAvailable will return true or false
```

Comment: I guess, OP's point was to find out whether duplicate values exist not to check if particular value is seen.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = [
  {
   id: 1,
   sku: "aaaa"
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   sku: "bbbb"
  },
  {
   id: 3,
   sku: "cccc"
  },
  {
   id: 4,
   sku: "aaaa"
  }
];

a.reduce((acc, obj)=>{

    // looping through each sku & adding them in acc
    acc.push(obj.sku);
    
    // check if current sku already exits in acc.
    const duplicate = acc.filter(x=>x === obj.sku);
    
    if(duplicate.length>1){
          // do something or nothing with current obj as similar SKUs are found
          // i'm adding a new property called x=10 if same SKUs are found.
          obj.x = 10;
    }else{
          // do something or nothing with current obj as similar SKUs are found
          // i'm adding a new property called y=10 if not same SKUs.
          obj.y=10;
 }
 
 return acc;

}, []);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Your code does nested lookups with `.filter()`  inside `.reduce()` (O(n²)-time algorithm), which will perform unnecessarily slow if source array happens to be large enough. Furthermore, it doesn't make much sense to use `.reduce()` as long as you don't really use `acc`, so simple `.forEach()` would work pretty much fine.

Comment: OP doesn't ask for returning true or false either.

Comment: foreach can also be used but reduce would be a little performant.

Comment: *'...reduce woudl be ..performant'* if performance is your concern, you would gain much more with turning your algorithm to O(n)-time rather than doing microoptimizations with `.reduce()` vs `.forEach()`

Comment: *'...OP doesn't ask'*, OP's request was rather vague, but It seems to me executing some code block conditionally upon `true` or `false` wouldn't take them much effort

Comment: That way you can also say that OP's question is kinda incomplete. he doesn't talk about what exactly he wants. But of course, he doesn't want true or false answer as per his question.

Comment: Probably, I don't have that much of a mental connection to OP to know what they wanted, however `true`/`false` seems to me whole lot better suited answer to the question *'How can I check that there are more than one element'*  than console logging input array after suboptimal looping through it using inappropriate array method. `for(..`-loop would perform even better, by the way, but would appear much easier to comprehend.